# Misuse of go-r *

Tags: permissions, chmod

I am working on a test server. Was logged in as root and issued

```
cd /
chmod go-r *
```

I certainly revoked the write permissions for the users that I had created.

Did I revoke the permissions (r/w/x) from all the groups that were created for processes like mysql, httpd, ftp etc - or do they chown it?

How do I check that?

[Update]
I've restarted mysql and apache. mysqld is not running as root. Logs are being written. Checking what else would be a good idea?

Comment: short answer: you are better off reinstalling than trying to fix the types of extremely subtle, often silent problems that this will cause.

Comment: @strugee there isn't an `-R` in there, so this one is easily fixable...

Comment: Err, did you did this as "root"? What is the problem you are seeing?

Comment: @Braiam, Err, says "was logged in as root" at the top...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, `chmod go-r` doesn't remove write permissions, it removes read permissions. The contents of `/` is primarily directories; on directories read permission means you're allowed to list it. E.g., `ls /bin` will now give a permission denied (except for the directory owner and root, of course the owner is root in this case).

If that was a typo and you meant `chmod go-w`, then you indeed removed write permission. Likely the only directory which had write permission for **g**roup or **o**ther was `/tmp`; you need to fix that.

Thankfully, you didn't include `-R` (recursive) in your `chmod`, so this is fairly easy to fix: Just compare `ls -l /` on the test server to `ls -l /` on a similar server. Use `chmod` to set the permissions back as they should be.

Note that chmod will follow symlinks, so if you have any in your root directory, you'll need to confirm them separately.

Finally, you don't appear to understand the Unix permissions model. Each file and directory has *one* user (the owner) and *one* group. The owner can have read, write, and/or execute permissions on the file/directory. That's what `chmod u=...` sets. All members of the group can have the same set of permissions (`chmod g=...`). Finally, everyone else (others) gets the same set (`chmod o=...`).

Example:

```
$ ls -l /etc/exim4/passwd.client 
-rw-r----- 1 root Debian-exim 204 Oct 15  2006 /etc/exim4/passwd.client
|^^^^^^^^^|  |||| ^^^^^^^^^^^
|  perms  |  ||||    group
t         |  owner
         acl
```

`t` the type of file: blank for plain files, `d` for directories, `l` for symlinks, `c` for character devices, `p` for named pipes, `b` for block devices, and there are probably a few more I'm forgetting.

`acl` will be `+` if there is an ACL on this file, you can use `getfacl` to see it.

The `1` I didn't label is the link count; if you made a hard link to the file, both names would show 2. Add another, and they'd show 3, etc.

The permissions field is three characters for the owner (user); three for the group; and three for other. The owner (user) can **r**ead and **w**rite the file, but not execute (since there is a `-` instead of a `x` there). Members of the `Debian-exim` group can read the file, but get no other permissions. People who are neither the owner nor members of Debian-exim get no permissions to this file.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have restored the permissions. Yes, I am a noob wrt Unix Permission Model - will do a good reading before proceeding with the next set of updates.

Answer (score 2):

`chmod go-r *` doesn't affect special groups at all. It just affects the rights for the primary groups and the "others". The primary group for everything in `/` should be `root`. So that doesn't change anything at all as root can do whatever he wants anyway.

The other accounts usually do not read the contents of the directories in `/` as they know their paths. Accessing these paths is still possible (due to the `x` permission).

Whether groups which you have created still have explicit read permission in these directories depends on it whether ACLs are used. If ACLs are present then the `ls -l` output changes from

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

to

```
drwxr-xr-x+
```

The ACL content can bee seen with `getfacl`.

The main question is: Why should one prevent groups from reading directories in `/`?